# How to make HStack fill its parent view's width (Scroll View)

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, hstack

I created a tabBar including 2 tabs. It has a horizontal scrollBar which includes a HStack view. But the HStack view only takes a part of screen width as screenshot in below. I used `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`, however it changed nothing.

What I want is to make HStack view takes all the screen width size. Please see the 2nd screenshot in below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                TextClipView().tag(0)
                BookView().tag(1)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            TabBarView(currentTab: $currentTab)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var tabBarOptions: [String] = ["text.bubble", "book"]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(Array(zip(tabBarOptions.indices, tabBarOptions)),
                        id: \.0,
                        content: {
                    index, name in
                    TabBarItem(currentTab: $currentTab, 
                               namespace: namespace,
                               tabBarItemName: name,
                               tab: index)
                })
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .border(.red, width: 4)
        }
        .frame(height: 80)
        .border(.green, width: 2)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct TabBarItem: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var tabBarItemName: String
    var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            currentTab = tab
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: tabBarItemName)
                    .font(.title)
                if currentTab == tab {
                    Color.black
                        .frame(height: 2)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "underline",
                                               in: namespace,
                                               properties: .frame)
                } else {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 2)
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: currentTab)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: To make the `HStack` take up the entire width of its parent view, you can use the `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier on the `ScrollView` itself

Comment: @Saleh7 I tried this, but no help. And currently ScrollView already take the full width of screen.

Comment: If the `HStack` takes up the whole width of the screen, it wouldn't be able to display everything when there are more tabs. Do you want it to only take up the whole width when its natural width is smaller than the screen width? And how do you want the buttons to be aligned horizontally?

Comment: @Sweeper please check the 2nd screenshot, that is what I want, and I could achieve that by setting HStack's frame width to fixed 400, but that is not ideal solution.

Comment: Okay, I see what you want when there are two tabs, but it is still unclear what you want when there are more tabs. What should happen when the screen width is unable to show all the tabs all at once?

Comment: @Sweeper, actually the tabs number is fixed from my design, 2 or 3. Thus, I don't need to consider for more.

Comment: Okay, so the `ScrollView` is just there to achieve a "bounciness"?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes I want that animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you are using a `ScrollView` because there might be times when the width of the content exceeds the available width.

To make the content fill the `Scrollview` when its ideal width is smaller, you can use a `GeometryReader` to measure the width and then set this as `minWidth` on the `HStack`.

Like this:

```swift
// TabBarView

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                // content as before
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(minWidth: proxy.size.width)
            .border(.red, width: 4)
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 80)
    .border(.green, width: 2)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: Yes, GeometryReader could get the parent's view size, in this case the screen width. This works.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct TabBarView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var tabBarOptions: [String] = ["text.bubble", "book", "star", "heart", "message"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(Array(zip(tabBarOptions.indices, tabBarOptions)), id: \.0) { index, name in
                    TabBarItem(currentTab: $currentTab, namespace: namespace, tabBarItemName: name, tab: index)
                }
                Spacer() // Add a Spacer to push buttons to the leading edge when they don't fit
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Allow HStack to expand only when needed
        }
        .frame(height: 80)
        .border(.green, width: 2)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

`Spacer` is added after the buttons in the `HStack`. This Spacer pushes the buttons to the leading edge when they don't fit within the available width. Additionally, we use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` on the `HStack` to allow it to expand only when its natural width is smaller than the screen width. This way, it will display all the tabs when they fit, and if there are more tabs than can fit, it will allow horizontal scrolling within the `ScrollView`.

**Try it :)**

Comment: Already tried my friend, no changes.

Comment: Here's an updated version of your TabBarView that handles this scenario: