# Dynamic Type: Use ScrollView instead of Spacers if required

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have content within an HStack that is narrower than the available space and use Spacers to fill the entire width. However, because of dynamic font size, the content can get too large, and a ScrollView is required instead of the Spacers. But Spacers don't work within Scrollviews.

An example with simple Text. The Text should neither be wrapped nor abbreviated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewSandbox: View {
    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello,")
                Spacer()
                Text("World!")
            }.lineLimit(1)
//        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ScrollViewSandbox()
}
```

At default font size, everything is fine:
[image]

At some point, a ScrollView is required instead of Spacers as the content is too wide:
[image]

A ScrollView makes the Text readable again, but then Spacers don't work anymore, and everything is left aligned:
[image]

I can use GeometryReader to set HStack minWidth and solve the issue above. However, this causes the content of GeometryReader to shrink to the wrong height when used within a (vertical) ScrollView, causing overlapping.

Example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewSandbox: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { prox in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                    }.frame(minWidth: prox.size.width)
                }
            }
            Text("Another line")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ScrollViewSandbox()
}
```

How it looks like
[image]

So overall, I want to use the Spacers as long as the content is narrower than the available space and use the ScrollView if the content is larger than the available space. How can I archive that behavior?

Comment: If the texts are large enough that it needs to be scrolled, you don't want any spaces between them. Is that right?

Comment: Try using a `GeometryReader` and set the `minWidth` of the `HStack`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751133/5133585)

Comment: @Sweeper I said thank you too soon. I use the horizontal ScrollView inside a vertical ScrollView. The GeometryReader causes the height to be lost and overlapping occurs.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of that problem and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem with the horizontal `ScrollView` was solved by nesting it inside a `GeometryReader`, as per the answer to [How to make HStack fill its parent view's width (Scroll View)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751133/20386264) (it was my answer).

The new problem is that the height of the `GeometryReader` is wrong. Normally, a `GeometryReader` is greedy and uses all the space available, but because it is nested inside another `ScrollView` (this time, one that scrolls vertically), it shrinks to a minimum. This is why the last `Text` is seen to overlap the content of the `HStack`.

Here are two workarounds:

**1. Move the outer `ScrollView` inside the `GeometryReader`**

If you nest the outer `ScrollView` inside the `GeometryReader`, instead of vice versa, then the `GeometryReader` occupies all of the available space in the usual way.

However, two additional changes are required with this approach:

- An additional `VStack` is required, to define the layout for the views inside the `GeometryReader`
- To force the outer `ScrollView` to adopt its ideal height, instead of its maximum height, `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` can be applied.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { prox in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Line 1")
                            Text("Line 2")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: prox.size.width)
                }
                .background(.yellow)
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            Text("Another line")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**2. Show the nested `GeometryReader` in an overlay**

If the original hierarchy is used, where a `ScrollView` is the top-level container, then the problem with the incorrect height for the `GeometryReader` can be solved by establishing the footprint for the `HStack` using hidden content. The `GeometryReader` can then be shown in an overlay over this hidden content.

```swift
struct ScrollViewSandbox: View {
    
    private var footprint: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(".")
            Text(".")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .hidden()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            footprint
                .background(.yellow)
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { prox in
                        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Line 1")
                                    Text("Line 2")
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Line 1")
                                    Text("Line 2")
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Line 1")
                                    Text("Line 2")
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(minWidth: prox.size.width)
                        }
                    }
                }
            Text("Another line")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the same as before.

For the example here, the footprint just consists of two lines of dummy text. This is sufficient for determining the height of the main content. If the main content is not so predictable, then you could always build the footprint by using a copy of the main content.

Comment: Answer updated with another workaround

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting IOS16 or above you could use `ViewThatFits`. This layout container chooses the first view in the closure that fits the given parent container, [docu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits).

e.g.:

```
struct ScrollViewSandbox: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits{
            subview
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                subview
            }
        }
    }
    
    var subview: some View{
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
            }
        }.lineLimit(1)
    }
}
```