# ScrollView: content alignment issue

Tags: swiftui

I have to show some items that may exceed the available horizontal space.

I am using a ScrollView and everything works fine when the items occupy more than the available space: the items are right aligned.

[image]

When the items occupy less space than the available they are left  aligned instead:

[image]

How do I align them to the right?

I have tried to add a Spacer() and to change the frame size but nothing works.

Down here my code.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var buffer: String
    @State private var size = 50
    @State private var selectedSize = 1

    init() {
        buffer = "0"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            Grid {
                GridRow {
                    Text("Number Of Items")
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)

                    Picker("", selection: $selectedSize) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< size, id: \.self) { idx in
                            Text("\(idx)")
                                .tag(idx)
                        }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .pickerStyle(.automatic)
                    .onChange(of: selectedSize) { _, _ in
                        buffer = "0".padding(toLength: selectedSize, withPad: "0", startingAt: 0)
                    }
                }

                GridRow {
                    Text("Items")
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)

                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        ScrollViewReader { value in
                            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                                // Spacer()
                                ForEach(0 ..< buffer.count, id: \.self) { idx in
                                    ItemView(idx: buffer.count - 1 - idx, value: buffer[idx])
                                        .background(.gray)
                                }
                                .onChange(of: buffer.count) {
                                    value.scrollTo(buffer.count - 1)
                                }
                            }
                            // .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                            .background(.green)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(.blue)
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var idx: Int
    var value: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(idx)")
            Spacer()
            Text(value)
        }
        .frame(width: 20, height: 45)
        .border(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting `.frame(minWidth: availableWidth, alignment: .trailing)` on the `HStack` inside the `ScrollView`. A `GeometryReader` can be used to find the available width. See the answer to [How to make HStack fill its parent view's width (Scroll View)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751133/20386264) for details.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix is to apply a `minWidth` to the `HStack` inside the `Scrollview`, as explained in the answer to [How to make HStack fill its parent view's width (Scroll View)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751133/20386264) (it was my answer).

However, the difficult part is finding the width to set.

If you try to wrap the `ScrollView` with a `GeometryReader` then this expands vertically and the `GridRow` becomes very tall. So another way is to use dummy content to establish the footprint for the grid cell, then show the actual scrollable content in an overlay. Doing it this way, the `GeometryReader` adopts the frame of the footprint.

```swift
GridRow {
    Text("Items")
        .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)

    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        ItemView(idx: 0, value: ".")
    }
    .hidden()
    .overlay {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { value in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< buffer.count, id: \.self) { idx in
                            ItemView(idx: buffer.count - 1 - idx, value: String(Array(buffer)[idx]))
                                .background(.gray)
                        }
                        .onChange(of: buffer.count) {
                            value.scrollTo(buffer.count - 1)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: proxy.size.width, alignment: .trailing)
                    .background(.green)
                }
            }
            .background(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, if you are targeting iOS 17 and above then [*Sweeper*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751167/20386264) to the other post would provide a much simpler solution.

Comment: FYI: I used the Sweeper's answer. Actually much more simple.

Comment: @Fab Pleased to hear you found a solution. I agree, using `.containerRelativeFrame` is much simpler... if it is available. Don't forget to upvote *Sweeper*'s answer ;)