# Find horizontal space without geometry reader

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to expand an image to the full available width in the view. To do this I use `.frame(width: geometry.size.width)`. However, this doesn't work when the geometry reader is inside a scroll view. I know the geometry reader must be outside of the scroll view for this to work. In my case I cannot refactor for that. Is there any way I can make the image utilize the full available width in the view while being in a scroll view? Note that in different sections of my app the available space will be of different size.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct UploadHustleCamera: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)//some random width
                
                Text("hello")//some random text
                
                Spacer()
                
                //does not work since in scroll view
                GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                     KFImage(URL(string: "https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w1200/2023/09/instagram-image-size.jpg"))
                          .resizable()
                          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                          .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                          .cornerRadius(18)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why can you not refactor? Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx putting the geometry reader outside of the scroll view means that the full width of the screen will always be the value of geo.size.width. What if my scroll view contains elements where each element has multiple objects in an HStack? In this case when I try to use geo.size.width I will get the full screen width which is not the available space for the image since it's next to other things.

Comment: The answer to [ScrollView: content alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916227/20386264) might help

Comment: Your `ScrollView` is scrolling vertically. So the `Spacer` in the `HStack` will work and scaling to fit should also work. Try removing the `GeometryReader` and the `.aspectRatio` and `.frame` modifiers on the image. Then add `.scaledToFit()` as replacement.

Comment: @BenzyNeez the **.scaledToFit()** did in fact work!

Comment: @BenzyNeez could you look at the following question. Your solution here doesn't work for my video player: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980011/resize-video-player-inside-scroll-view-swift-ui