# Resize Video Player Inside Scroll View Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a video player that retains its normal size outside of a scroll view. However when embedded inside a scroll view its scaling is off. I want the video player to occupy all available horizontal space and then adjust its vertical size based on the ration of available horizontal space. I tried using scaled to fill/fit but this didn't work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct UploadHustleCamera: View {
   let url: URL
   var body: some View {
       ScrollView {
           HStack {
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)//some random width
               
               Text("hello")//some random text
               
               Spacer()
               
               HustleVideoPlayer(url: url)
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true) * 0.75)
           }
       }
   }
}

struct HustleVideoPlayer: View {
   let url: URL
   @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
   
   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           VideoPlayer(player: $player).id(viewID)
       }
       .onAppear {
           player = AVPlayer(url: url)
           self.player.play()
       }
   }
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   @Binding var player : AVPlayer
   
   func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

       let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
       controller.player = player
       controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
       controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       return controller
   }
   
   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
```

Comment: Try taking a look at the solutions to [How to make HStack fill its parent view's width (Scroll View)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77751023/20386264), except that in this case, your `ScrollView` is scrolling vertically. If you are targeting iOS 17 then try applying `.containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)` to the `HStack` inside the `ScrollView`. If that doesn't work, you could use the approach of an overlay for showing the video player.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I was able to make the video player fill the available horizontal width but then the vertical width is off. Im targeting iOS 15-17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if you remove the `.frame` modifier. You might also want to set a wider aspect ratio (the default is 1:1):

```swift
HustleVideoPlayer(url: url)
    .aspectRatio(3.0 / 2.0, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, the aspect ratio was always 1:1. Im not sure having an aspect ratio of 3/2 would fix it because some videos have different sizes. Is there anyway to maintain the original aspect ratio and have the video fill the full width?

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Pleased to hear it worked, thanks for accepting the answer. I don't think the video player lets you read the aspect ratio for the underlying video, but maybe you can configure it somewhere in connection with the URL? In my tests, I found the player was capable of showing the video with any aspect ratio you gave it. So maybe you can fix it to the most common ratio, perhaps 16:9?

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower This post might help for getting the aspect ratio: [Swift - How to get video dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44879386/20386264)